# PHP - how to stream content with Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Tags: php, stream, comet

I'm trying to implement a simple stream test using php. with the following code I can see the response is being streamed - using firebug net tab.

However the content does not get rendered until the response is done.
What am I missing?

```
header('Content-Encoding: chunked');
header('Transfer-Encoding: chunked');
header('Content-Type: text/html');
header('Connection: keep-alive');
flush();
ob_flush();

for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    dump_chunk('<script type="text/javascript">console.log(' . $i . ')</script>');
    flush();
    ob_flush();
    sleep(1);
}

function dump_chunk($chunk) {
    echo sprintf("%x\r\n", strlen($chunk));
    echo $chunk;
    echo "\r\n";
}
```

Comment: `chunked` is not a valid token for `Content-Encoding`.

Comment: I think that this can be handled by apache.

Comment: this is basically a copy paste code. (more or less) from http://inchoo.net/tools-frameworks/chunked-transfer-encoding/

Answer (score 0):

This is generally not something you'd handle manually in PHP. The server (Apache, Nginx, or whatever you use) does it for you. I've been struggling with this too and in my case the issue was that the responses were sent in chunks of 4kB and no smaller chunk could be sent no matter what you did in PHP.

So just take a look at whatever is set in `ini_get('output_buffering')`. If it's 0 or 1, it means 'Off' and 'On' respectively. In that case it's either turned off completely, or it's some kind of a default value, likely to be the same 4kB or something similar. Otherwise it's gonna be an exact number of bytes.

After that you can pad your chunk with some white-space (or whatever works in your case) to make sure you force it to echo out the full 4kB (or however large the output buffer is).

```
$bufferSize = (int) ini_get('output_buffering');
if ($bufferSize < 2) { // 'On' or 'Off'
    $bufferSize = 4 * 1024; // Adjust this to your system default.
}

ob_end_flush();

for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    dump_chunk('<script>...', $bufferSize);
    sleep(1);
}

function dump_chunk(string $chunk, int $bufferSize): void {
    echo str_pad($chunk, $bufferSize, ' ');
}
```

In my case doing `ob_end_flush` at the beginning worked well and no further buffer flushing was needed but you'll probably have to figure out what works with your setup.